# Есть ли готовые библиотеки календаря для telegram bot реализованные на php?

Tags: php, telegram-bot

Возможно кому то встречались готовые решения(библиотеки) подобные этой https://github.com/grcanosa/telegram-calendar-keyboard, написанные на php
Буду очень благодарен за любую информацию

Comment: https://github.com/miserenkov/telegram-bot-calendar ?

Comment: @Total Pusher Спасибо огромное!)
Напишите в ответ чтобы я мог отметить вас)

Comment: Я просто погуглил "telegram bot calendar php". Ну точнее я использую поиск duduckgo, он и сразу сниппеты с SO показывает

Comment: @TotalPusher тоже гуглил но обычным способом и ничего не нашел)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[github.com/miserenkov/telegram-bot-calendar](http://github.com/miserenkov/telegram-bot-calendar)

Comment: Пожалуйста, приведите в ответе небольшой пример использования библиотеки. Ответы-ссылки -- не очень хорошая практика, также неплохо пояснять возможности библиотеки небольшим примером из документации или личного опыта.

Comment: Связанная тема на мета-сайте: https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9491/213987

Comment: @AK как ТС может дать пример, если только нашел либу?)